How to understand Newton’s third laws correctly?
The first question: (In a tug-of-war between A and B, the rope has mass) Analyzing the force on the rope, the resultant force is to the right, so it moves to the right. A exerts a force of 4N to the left on the rope, and the rope exerts a force of 4N to the right on A. At this point, analyzing the forces on A, A is subjected to a 4N tension to the right and a 4N frictional force to the left from the ground. So is A in a state of equilibrium? However, this conclusion does not conform to the objective fact that the rope is moving. This is the first question.
In the second scenario (a continuation of the first), two boxers' fists collide, with boxer A's fist exerting a force of 4N to the left and boxer B's fist exerting a force of 6N to the right. What is the magnitude of the interaction force between them? According to my understanding, based on Newton's third law, the reasoning is similar to the first scenario. Boxer A experiences a reactive force of 4N to the left, so his own muscles must generate a force of 4N to the right. Is he in equilibrium? If we imagine boxer A as an object receiving a force of 6N to the left and 4N to the right, the net force should be 2N, causing him to move to the left. How do we reconcile these two situations?

Recall that forces don't tell you anything about the instantaneous velocity - only about acceleration.

Closing this seems appropriate although answers could be given.

It is an easy edit for the OP to just pick one and delete the other. Then it can be repoened

(a) "Analyzing the force on the rope, the resultant force is to the right, so it moves to the right."
The rope would be accelerating to the right. It might even be moving to the left, but with decreasing speed.

Question 1
First, I want to note that the ropes instantaneous motion (velocity) is independent of the forces applied to it; the force tells you how the rope is accelerating, not how it is moving.
If we assume that $B$ is applying a greater force than $A$ to the rope, then the rope will accelerate to the left (and realistically, $B$ is winning the tug-of-war). In this situation, $A$ is not at equilibrium. If $A$ pulls left on the rope with a force of 4 N, then the rope will also pull A to the right with a force of 4 N, as per Newton's 3rd law. But in the situation you describe, the friction between $A$ and the ground will be less than 4 N, and therefore $A$ accelerates to the right.
Question 2
When two objects $A$ and $B$ collide, the force exerted on $A$ (by $B$) is equivalent in magnitude to the force extered on $B$ (by $A$), i.e. $F_{AB} = - F_{BA}$. Therefore the premise of your question is faulty; you cannot say that boxer $A$'s fist exerts a force of 4 N, while boxer $B$'s fist exerts a force of 6 N. The two forces have to be equal.
If the two boxers were floating in vacuum, the collision would cause both of them to recoil and float away from each other with a speed inversely proportional to their mass. The reason this doesn't happen in the ring is due to the friction between the boxers' feet and the floor. The boxer who experiences the least friction will move most.
It is worth reiterating the last point; it is not the boxer with the strongest punch who moves the least. Aassuming the two boxers have the same coefficients of friction with the floor, it is always the heaviest boxer who moves the least, regardless of the strength of his/her punch ). The same is true in tug-of-war; if you want to win tug-of-war, don't pick people with strong arms; pick the people with the largest body mass, and the best shoes.

Thank you!!!!!!!! I totally knew where was wrong in my thought. You’re my hero! I couldn’t fall asleep last night because I didn’t work it out. I can’t describe my appreciation for you in language !!!!
